# It says I cannot ask 6 questions in 24 hours but I only asked 5?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I had 6 questions asked but deleted one today to ask another, more appropriate question.
However now I am stuck with the error message stating that I asked 6 questions. Does the system not update the fact I deleted one question, which means I only asked 5 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Deleted questions count towards the daily limit total.

If they didn't, people would just delete one to ask a new one, and that's not really something we would like to encourage. Unless you deleted your question seconds after you posted it, chances are people read it and reviewed it (voted on it and/or commented). Their time is as valuable as yours and if you find yourself deleting your questions often, perhaps you should start considering spending a bit more time researching and formulating your questions *before* you post them.

Comment: But that just prevented me from asking a better, more useful question ...I think this feature makes it counter-productive.

Comment: @NLed Instead of deleting it, you should edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @bluefeet it's an unrelated question ... the question I had was solved in another question, so it wasn't really needed. The question I have now is more important and I can't ask it.

Comment: @NLed See my update. Also, all you have to do is wait a day, if asking your question is so urgent that you can't wait a day, perhaps you should consider hiring a professional.

Comment: @NLed, it should be *impossible* to ask 6 questions in a day. Do some research. Spend (a lot of) your own time before you ask for ours.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Although I agree with you, but keep in mind that some people might have time constraints in their projects, and may have already spent a lot of time looking for a solution on their own and failing.

Comment: @Yannis Fair enough

Comment: @NLed: Everyone has time constraints. Those *answering* questions have time constraints too - asking lots of questions because you feel you don't have enough time to research them properly first hurts everyone, because it acts as a distraction from those questions which *have* been researched properly. Fundamentally, if your project absolutely depends on being able to get help for questions that you don't have time to research, your project is in big trouble, and you shouldn't expect to be bailed out by Stack Overflow. (Don't forget that *showing* existing research is part of a good question.)

Comment: @NLed If you want to be asking more than 5 questions in a single day then there is simply no way you'll have spent the time and effort needed to make them quality questions.  If you're asking that many, chances are some or all of them are of low quality.  The site goes out of it's way to make asking low quality questions hard.

Comment: @NLed [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557309/print-in-command-window-without-ans-in-matlab) could definitely have been found with a bit of research and playing around, as even if you are not familiar with Matlab, it's about dealing with the return value of a function.  I don't think they are of low structural or grammatical quality, and thanks for that, but take some more time to bang your head against the wall and it will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: @NLed Your questions are of low quality.  The oldest two are just you listing requirements and asking us to do your work for you.  You demonstrated no effort at all.  The third I couldn't comment on without domain knowledge, but based on the comments of others, you should have spent more time on it.  The fourth is pretty good.  Certainly the best of the five.  I'd say that's your one good question of the day.  The fifth was something I found the answer to in 15 seconds of googling with no knowledge of the domain at all; you didn't do your research.

Comment: @jonsca Thank you, that's more helpful criticism than Servy and will consider spending more time researching before asking.

Comment: @Servy Okay, if you say so my friend :)

Comment: @NLed How it the criticism not helpful?  I went out of my way to read each of your questions in detail and provided feedback to you on your questions *at your own request*.  Just because you didn't like the information my comment contained doesn't mean it's wrong, or that it's not helpful.

Comment: @NLed I definitely don't disagree with the other commenters, I was just pointing out what I thought was the one that you definitely, regardless of experience, could have worked through.  I think everyone has made some good points, and is ultimately looking out for you in the end.  I don't think Servy meant anything malicious at all by his observations.